# Animation Nodes Appending

Tags: animation-nodes

After appending Animation Nodes tree and selecting object in the new scene by eyedropper, AN doesn't work. Even Viewer on Time Info is freezed.
How can I Append or use Nodes in another scenes?

Comment: Do you have a second scene in your file ? When I append a node tree sometimes it also adds a new scene.

Comment: You're right. In Animation Nodes "N" panel i have to change Scene